# Simple DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to get into DataBinding and currently I'm stuck. I just can't get it to work. I read many tutorials, but honestly, none of the really helped me. I know what DataBinding is and why it's cool to use it, but I never came across a tutorial that showed me what to do **in my code**. They all just assume I know what I have to do there and only show the XAML side.

This is my class:

```
public class Test : Window
{
    public IList<String> data { get; set; }

    public Test() {
        data = new List<String>();
        InitializeComponents();
        data.Add("Hello");
        data.Add("World");
    }
}
```

And here's my XAML

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,6"
    Name="SourceDocumentsList" Width="202"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=data}" />
```

Yet, nothing is displayed when I render the window. How can something this easy fail? What am I doing wrong here?

The way I understand it, I tell the Listbox that it should bind itself to the `data` property of the currently running application, which is my class `Test`.

Comment: You can replace `Path=data` with `Path=MainWindow.data` if your class Test is your startup Window and it will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those properties into a separate class like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<String> Data { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Data.Add("Hello");
        Data.Add("World");
    }
}
```

Change your Window Code Behind as

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

Your Xaml will look less complicated

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,6"
Name="SourceDocumentsList" Width="202"
ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

This is what we call moving into MVVM pattern. Happy Coding !

Comment: But doesn't that mean I have to hold two separate data structures? One ViewModel and one that is the actual data model?

Comment: Yes, Because your actual data model may contain more than what your View requires or may not contain what View requires. So ViewModel converts your model to the way View requires. Basically VM sits as the intermediate and helps to View and Model not to be coupled. Makes the things look cleaner and more maintainable

Comment: What if I have several data structures I need to bind to. Should I just add them all to one ViewModel-class in separate properties, or make a new ViewModel for every "actual" model?

Comment: Viewmodel will be one place for the View to look for its binding properties. So all of them will be properties inside the ViewModel.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - You can think of it like every View should have a separate VM. If you are using different DS for the same view, you can add it to the same VM. And moreover, you can look for basic MVVM architecture for WPF so that you can design and structure your application better. You can go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article for information..

Answer (score 2):

The currently running application is **not** that class, it's just a window, what you bind to is the instance of the `App` class. You cannot statically get that window instance this way. How the binding should be made depends on where that XAML is (if it is in the `Test` window you can for example use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}` instead).

I would recommend reading the [MSDN documentation on data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and this [article on debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I read the MSDN documentation but I found it extremly difficult to understand, as I can't apply any of the examples to what I want to do. Apart from that I can't seem to find any reference about what certain keywords mean (like `x:Static`, `RelativeSource` etc.). They just pop up and you have to understand them...

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: No you don't have to understand them, you can look them up, they all have their own documentation: [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx), [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)